# Can't Get readshapefile() to read the .shp

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

So I've recently gotten into mapmaking with Python using matplotlib and Basemap. For some reason my code breaks when I go to execute m.readshapefile() because it can't find the .shp.

I downloaded the .zip for [this](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-populated-places/) and put it on my desktop at C:\Users\mattd\Desktop\pop\ne_110m_populated_places. I put

```
m.readshapefile('C:\Users\mattd\Desktop\pop\ne_110m_populated_places', 
            'populated_places')
```

and it can't breaks because it can't find the file.

Comment: Help us help you by [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you attached, there was no file named `populated_places`
I did find a `ne_110m_populated_places.shp`. Also, it's also good practice to name your variables what they are and do sanity checks in your own code instead of relying on libraries to do that for you.

```
from os import path

shape_dir = 'C:\Users\mattd\Desktop\pop\ne_110m_populated_places'
shape_file = 'ne_110m_populated_places'
shape_file_full = shape_file + '.shp'

# check if we provided valid paths to our file and directory
if path.isdir(shape_dir) is False:
    print ("%s does not exist!" % (shape_dir))
    quit()

if path.isfile(shape_file_fill) is False:
    print ("%s does not exist" % (shape_file_full))
    quit()

# if it makes it here then you know it's an issue with the library
base_map = Basemap(...)
base_map.readshapefile(shape_dir, shape_file)
```